# Twig / Symfony2 - using a variable inside array merge

Tags: symfony, twig

```
{% set var_name1 = "hello" %}
{% set var_name2 = "there" %}
{% array1|merge({var_name1: var_name2}) %}
```

I was hoping the code above would add this to array1:

```
hello:there
```

...but it adds:

```
var_name1:there
```

I've tried wrapping {{ }} around var_name1. Is it possible to add a record to an array and use a variable for the key?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Enclose the key name in brackets:

```
{% array1|merge({(var_name1): var_name2}) %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that if var_name1 is a numeric value, it won't work.
You'll have to concat it with a string value :

```
{% set array1 = array1|merge({(var_name1~'_'): var_name2}) %}
```