# Setting a key to array from a variable in Twig

Tags: twig

I want to substitute a value from a variable as a key to an array. I have that code:

```
{{ blogPost.getContent()|replace({truncationMark: ''})|raw }}
```

I've tried the way, but I've encountered with a problem: truncationMark is interpretated as string! It even replaces "truncationMark" substring in blogpost.getContent().

So what I have do to solve the problem?

I'd be thankful for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615615/twig-symfony2-using-a-variable-inside-array-merge this is the answer.